# How to execute command from Java program

Tags: java, selenium

I need to execute this command to stop selenium server.

```
wmic path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%selenium-server%'"  Call Terminate
```

from my java program. I tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command as a single string escaped")
```

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])
```

but it is not getting executed. When I execute the same command from cmd it is working fine. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping/handling white spaces are better run done with [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29):

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir) 
  throws IOException
```

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process
>   with the specified environment and working directory.

then wait for the process to end using the [process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) methode.